# I am having problems with launching a minecraft server, An UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

```
Uncaught exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception occurred when launching the server!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.server.FabricServerLauncher.main(FabricServerLauncher.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking MC server bundler: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.BundlerProcessor.process(BundlerProcessor.java:102)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.locateGame(MinecraftGameProvider.java:190)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.createGameProvider(Knot.java:177)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:130)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:68)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotServer.main(KnotServer.java:23)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.server.FabricServerLauncher.main(FabricServerLauncher.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.BundlerProcessor$1.loadClass(BundlerProcessor.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.BundlerProcessor.process(BundlerProcessor.java:85)
    ... 6 more
```

Is the error code I get. I am launching a Fabric server, but normal server jars only give me "A Java Exception has occurred".

I am using Windows 11, that is probably part of the issue, and there might not be a fix, but I have to ask in case there is one.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` Install a later java version.

Answer (score 1):

https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/

You're trying to run a java 17 program with java 8

Upgrade your java installation to run it properly

Comment: Why am I so stupid?
Anyways, Thank you!